# group of rows under one of column name

Tags: mysql

I want one name of `req_group` contain id  by php, html like this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Kidney Profile :- (6,9,10)
Diabetes Profile :- (5,7)
Electrolytes & Trace Elements :- (8)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

this table in my sql

```
**id**  **result**  **unit**   **normal**       **req_group**
  6        33         mg/dl     N: 0.5 - 1.5     Kidney Profile
  5        44         mg/dl N : Up to 140    Diabetes Profile
  7        11         %         7.1 - 8          Diabetes Profile
  8        66         Ug/dl M : 70 -140F     Electrolytes profile
  9        43         mg/dl M : 3 - 7F       Kidney Profile
 10        34         ml/24    1000-2000     Kidney Profile
```

group like this:

```
Kidney Profile :- (6,9,10)

Diabetes Profile :- (5,7)

Electrolytes & Trace Elements :- (8)
```

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: it give me problem

Comment: What database are you using? Show your code.

Comment: mysql_query("select distinct req_group from request");

Comment: I don't see any use of `GROUP_CONCAT` or `GROUP BY` in that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to create a comma-separated list of a column from all the rows in a group.

```
SELECT req_group, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM request
GROUP BY req_group
```

Comment: my code used  $sss= mysql_query("SELECT req_group, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM request
GROUP BY req_group");
         while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($sss)){
             echo $rr['req_group'].'<br>';
             echo $rr['id'],'<br>';
         }

Comment: result:
Diabetes Profile

Electrolytes & Trace Elements

Kidney Profile

Comment: id  not display why??

Comment: i used AS after GROUP_CONCAT(id)  thank you dear Barmar